# ¿Como escapar caracteres ASCII a hexadecimal?

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy intentado escapar caracteres ASCII a hexadecimal utf8 que sean comprensibles para el terminal de linux.

Lo que estoy tratando de lograr es lo siguiente

```sh
echo -n ♥ | od -A n -t x1
// e2 99 a5 => \xe2\x99\xa5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente manera, quizás no se la mas elegante pero funciona perfectamente :)

```sh
escape() {
  echo -n $1 | hexdump -ve '1/1 " %.2x"' | sed 's/ /\\\x/g'
}
escape ♥ # \xe2\x99\xa5
```

[Fuente](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/268104-convert-utf-8-file-ascii-iso8859-1-replace-characters.html)